# How to get ExtJS Grid scroll so last row is at the top of view

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to make my extjs cause a grid row to scroll to the top of the grid so I can float another component just below it. This seems to be an issue if the target row is one of the last rows. 
I was thinking I might resize the height of 's parent container but I was hoping there might be a trick in the framework.

This project uses ExtJS version 4.2.2

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking. If it's the last row in the grid, then that means it's at the end of the scroll boundary.

Comment: Thats my issue. Under normal circumstances, a grid will only scroll to until the last row comes into view. I'd like the grid to keep scrolling until the last row at the top of the grid's view table.